# PHP Slim get variables

Tags: php, slim

I have a search page. I want the Slim to get parameters from URLs like the one below:
`mywebsite.com/search/search-category/search-strings/min-price/max-price`
for example:
`mywebsite.com/search/laptops/asus/500/2000`.

this can be done by this code:

```
$app->get('/:type/:str/:minprice/:maxprice', function ($type,$str,$minprice,$maxprice) {

});
```

but the problem is that if I navigate to: `mywebsite.com/search/laptops/asus`.
it gives me 404 error and messes the entire page up, but I want it to show only laptops with "asus" in their titles.

how can I achieve this?
I want the Slim to get the list of parameters and parse them like below:

```
if there is no parameter, then show all products (mywebsite.com/search/).
---------------------------------------
if only one parameter is present, then it's category (mywebsite.com/search/laptops).
---------------------------------------
if 2 parameters are present, then the first one is category and the second one is keyword (mywebsite.com/search/laptops/apple/).
---------------------------------------
and so on the 3rd one is minprice and the 4th one is maxprice.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slim allows for optional parameters:

http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/params/#optional-route-parameters